# Restrict API public access

Tags: android, laravel, api

I am building a API using Laravel and consuming it on the android mobile app. I only want it to be consumed by my application, and prevent access to the public. Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) to restrict access to public. You can simply generate token and pass it into headers, or use basic authentication with username and password and check it in your middleware.

If any parameter or authentication method not passes in meddleware just type `abort(401)` and it returns `401 Unauthenticated`

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks for the idea. Is it possible to restrict the API only for external apps (third party apps or any mobile apps) and consume it with out restriction with in the Laravel App (for example using Vue.js)

Comment: Yes of course. You can pass access-controll-allow-origin header and pass any value you want there. for example in middleware's `handle(Request $request, $next){}` method you can write: `return $next($request)->header('Access-Controll-Allow-Origin', 'https://yoursite.com');`, So only yoursite.com will be allowed to access that api

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use Laravel Airlock.

Here is the documentation for it: https://laravel.com/docs/master/airlock

As there is no code provided with the question, I can't help you with concrete code examples, but in the documentation, it is really nicely explained, so you shouldn't have any problems to integrate it with your app.

You can take a look at this article for more examples: https://medium.com/@JillevdWeerd/app-authentication-with-laravel-airlock-36e3d2027994

Hope this helps.